# Button to copy paste in Excel

Tags: database, windows, excel, button, copy-paste

Ok so i write some words in cells from C3 to C9.
Then i want a button that copies and pastes this 6 blocks to cells from H3 to H9.

I already did the code for this.

```
Sub Save_Click() 
Range("C3:C9").Copy 
Range("H3:H9").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

But what i need now is for the program to register if cells from H3 to H9 are empty or not and if they aren't empty it should paste it to cells from I3 to I9 and if those aren't empty it should paste it in cells from J3 to J9 and so on and so on...

I found some other forums about this but i'm a complete noob in this and didn't get what i had to do. If someone knows what i have to do i would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to rely on a simple loop; also `Cells` makes things easier than a `Range` with letters on it. Here you have a sample code:

```
Sub Save_Click() 
Range("C3:C9").Copy
Dim curRange As Range
Dim curCol As Integer: curCol = 7
Dim completed As Boolean: completed = False
Do
    curCol = curCol + 1
    Set curRange = Range(Cells(3, curCol), Cells(9, curCol))

    If (WorksheetFunction.CountA(curRange) = 0) Then
       Exit Do
    End If
Loop While (Not completed)

curRange.PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: So i was playing with your code a little bit and i was wondering if it's possible to paste the words to a second worksheet? What i mean by that is that the cells C3 to C9 and the button is still on first sheet but location to which you then paste the words are on the second sheet.

Comment: @BlueNorris no problem at all. Bear in mind that Range("range name") is a short form for Sheets("Sheet name").Range("range name"), actually if you are using various sheets you should always include the Sheets("Sheet name") part to avoid problems.